# Redirect loop for special characters

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

The question at [how to symmetric transposition the coordinates about y = -tan(54º)x line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60776559/how-to-symmetric-transposition-the-coordinates-about-y-tan54%c2%bax-line) puts my browser into a redirect loop. Probably, that character in the URL is not handled properly in the backend?

Comment: I'm hitting that loop too.

Comment: See also MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345335/323179

Comment: No repo: I experience no problem with that link in Firefox 74.0 on Win 10 x64.

Comment: It looks like that we're going to need to know more about your system (i.e. what OS/Browser are you using?). Have you tried it on a fresh profile without any browser extensions?

Comment: @Makyen I've tried that on Ubuntu using the most current versions of Firefox and Chrome, both show an error message

Comment: @Makyen same on Safari and Firefox on my Macbook

Comment: I'm getting the same on Windows 10. Edge (Hmmm... cannot reach this page) / Chrome (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS) / Opera (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Windows 10 on Chrome, Edge or FF. Did you clear your cache?

Comment: @Cerbrus I've used private windows and I've never used Safari before on my pretty new Macbook - also, this looks strange if the bug is triggered in the exact same way on two different laptops in three different browsers. Something they have in common: I'm in Germany and all are using a german user interface

Comment: thanks for the report, we're canarying SO on AspNetCore, and you hit one of the issues, this will be resolved shortly

Comment: @m0sa in the past you used to just strip special characters from the URL, why change that? As far as I can tell, unicode characters in the URL still cause trouble in certain browsers, especially old or, as we now know, mobile.

Comment: Man, why does SO always have to be the coal mine? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou that was [a long time ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214531/convert-diacritics-to-normal-letters-in-the-profile-link/233832#233832)...

Comment: @HereticMonkey it wasn't just SO, this canary is running for all sites in the network that hit a specific server...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We've removed the affected server from rotation and a build will be going out shortly to address this problem. We've been testing a branch of our .NET Core port to find issues exactly like this so thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, Dean!